# Creating .lnk-file using only C++ and cmd

Tags: c++, cmd, autorun, lnk

I have an `.exe` file and I want to add it to Autorun without using explorer. I know way to my `.exe` file. For adding something to Autorun I should create `shortcut.lnk` and put it to `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`. I tried to use `cmd` command `mklink`, but this command creates `.symlink`, not `.lnk`.

How can I add my file to Autorun, apart from creating `.lnk` shortcut? 
How create `.lnk`, using **only** C++ and `cmd` (not js, Powershell, BAT,  etc.)
I know, that `.lnk` is just a txt file in HEX code? so I can put text with address in it and change add-in. It is not good way, in my opinion.

Comment: Search for ways to write to the Windows registry using C++. I am confident there are many.

Answer (score 2):

.lnk is a [binary file with specific format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd871305.aspx). The proper way to enable autorun is to create a registry entry in [Run or RunOnce](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/SetupApi/run-and-runonce-registry-keys) sections.